# Nginx SERVER ENV not persisting with CName

Tags: php, nginx, cname

Weird problem. In my Nginx vhost configuration I am setting variable such as ENV to tell PHP if it should act differently depending on the environment.

For example:

```
location / {
...
   fastcgi_param   ENV  production;
...
}
```

And then PHP reads it like:

```
<?php

if($SERVER['ENV'] == 'production' {
//Do This
} else {
//Do That
}
```

This works normally. But when the site is accessed through a cname, it seems the ENV variable is no longer being read. What could be causing this?

Full Server BLock

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        root   /data/sites/www.example.com/public_html/;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?rt=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root   /data/sites/www.example.com/public_html/;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param  ENV  production;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `location` config block located? Inside a `server` block?

Comment: @Tomdarkness Yes it inside the server block for each vhost. Should it be elsewhere?

Comment: Can you post the `server` block?

Comment: @Tomdarkness posted above